# Convertir a mayúsculas el texto de un EditText mientras se escribe

Tags: android

Tengo un EditText al que le he agregado la propiedad *addTextChangedListener* y deseo que **mientras escribo** en el EditText el texto se convierta en mayúsculas.

Este es mi layout con mi EditText:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/ingresa_codigo_participacion"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:paddingRight="11dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor_edittext"
        />
```

Este es mi EditText:

```
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                myEditText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length()>0){
                    imgClearEdt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    imgClearEdt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿Ups, Mi respuesta no te sirvió?, conteste primeramente pero recibí un -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos formas de hacerlo...

Forma 1. Puedes usar lo siguiente en el XML de tu EditText para que todas las letras sean mayúsculas:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Forma 2. Con `addTextChangedListener` y `TextWatcher`:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable et) {
          String s = et.toString();
      if (!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()))
      {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         edittext.setText(s);
      }
      editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
    }
});
```

Ambas hacen exactamente lo mismo. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es definir en el `EditText` la propiedad:

```
   android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

esta propiedad [android:inputType="textCapCharacters"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType) forza a escribir en mayusculas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otra opción es definiendo un [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter) definiendo el método `InputFilter.AllCaps()` :

```
   EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
   myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

en este caso en el teclado no se mostrarán caracteres en mayúscula pero al escribirlos se mostrarán en mayúsculas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.